# aligning content:before within spans

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add and style content to the following HTML.  I do not have access to the HTML, and can only modify the css to get my desired results.

```
<body>
<div id="wallet">
    <span id="cost">$300.00</span>
    <span id="shipping">$20.00</span>
    <span id="taxes">$10.00</span>
</div>
</body>
```

The css / content I am adding is as follows:

```
#cost, #shipping, #taxes{
display:block;
text-align:right;
width:200px;
}

#cost:before{
content: "SUBTOTAL:";
}
#shipping:before{
content:"SHIPPING:";
}
#taxes:before{
content:"TAXES:";
}
```

What I would like is to have all of the semicolons in "Shipping:", "Taxes:", and "Subtitle:" aligned vertically.    And then all of the dollar values flush right within the span.  So the space between the colons and the dollar values will vary.  Is this possible using only css?  I have tried a number of combinations, attempting to float the before content left, and then align the text right, but that didn't work.

Also, I cannot access the variables to produce the dollar amounts.  So, I can't calculate whether the value is 2 digit, 3 digit, etc. and set css values from there.

If this isn't possible, at this point I would settle for having the words "Shipping:", "Sales Tax:", and "Total:" all aligned left and the dollar values aligned right.  Can't get this working, either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Fiddle for OP's stuff](http://jsfiddle.net/vSV48/)

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vSV48/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may float and size your pseudo elements : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/vSV48/3/)**

---

CSS:

```
#cost, #shipping, #taxes{
display:block;
text-align:right;
width:200px;
}
#wallet span:before {/* rule added */
  float:left;
  width:50%;/* tune this to your needs */
}
#cost:before{
content: "SUBTOTAL:";
}
#shipping:before{
content:"SHIPPING:";
}
#taxes:before{
content:"TAXES:";
}
```

Comment: with some extra tunning you can go a little further http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/vSV48/5/

Comment: You can also achieve this using absolute positioning of the pseudo elements.  In both cases, one needs to specify the right edge of the generated content, either setting the width to 50% (for floats) or the right offset to 50% (using absolute positioning).

Comment: @MarcAudet you are right, the point here is to give somehow layout to the pseudo so it doesn't follow text-align without breaking the line and being sized. personnaly i use absolute positionning as last options since it is not in the flow and not enough flexible to my taste :)

Comment: This is the most robust answer.  I have adjusted my css.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So pretty simple, you just have to float your pseudo classes, and adjust the margins accordingly.

Fiddle for demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/vSV48/2/

```
#cost:before{
    content: "SUBTOTAL:";
    float: left;
}
#shipping:before{
    content:"SHIPPING:";
    float: left;
    margin-left: 9px;
}
#taxes:before{
    content:"TAXES:";
    float: left;
    margin-left: 31px;
}
```

Comment: @user480029 no it's not exactly what you need, at least as you said you wanted the colons (which you mistyped as semicolons) to be vertically centered. Doing so is not easy at all.

Comment: This is not very robust, if you change the text or even the font size, then you need to adjust the left margin values...

Comment: @user480029 as much as I want the check, you should really look at GCyrillus' answer. Much better if you change fonts and text etc.

Comment: @King King -- yep.  got me on the colon vs. semi-colon.  But, I said "vertically aligned" (meaning lined up vertically), not vertically centered.  Even in the strictest css sense of alignment, you have to select an option.  You injected the "centered."

Comment: @Adjit Changed my accepted answer.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You could use align-content: flex-end; on span to push the prices to the right.

HTML

```
<div id="wallet">
    <span id="cost">$300.00</span>
    <span id="shipping">$20.00</span>
    <span id="taxes">$10.00</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#cost, #shipping, #taxes{
display:block;
text-align:right;
width:200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-content: flex-end;
}

#cost:before,
#shipping:before,
#taxes:before{
float: left;
}

#cost:before{
content: "SUBTOTAL:";
}
#shipping:before{
content:"SHIPPING:";
}
#taxes:before{
content:"TAXES:";
}
```

Check this demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/HalilTeker/vyAdE/

Comment: Your solution works regardless even without the `align-content` property.  You need to specify `display: flex` to use flexbox properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can align the generated content labels using absolute positioning:

```
#cost, #shipping, #taxes {
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    width:200px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    position: relative;
}
#cost:before {
    content:"SUBTOTAL:";
}
#shipping:before {
    content:"SHIPPING:";
}
#taxes:before {
    content:"TAXES:";
}
#wallet *:before {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Use the `right` offset on the `:before` pseudo-elements to position the labels to the right of the
dollar values.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/pepbk/

The advantage of this approach is that the labels are right justified regardless of the length of the words or the font size, a bit more robust.